# SSRS expression - convert Decimal to HH:mm

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

1. In SSRS dataset I have "Hours" column with values e.g. "8", "8,5" etc.
   And I need convert it to HH:mm format.

So ideal example:

8 -> 08:00

8,5 -> 08:30

2. And special question - is it possible if I have "XYZ" column contains "168" (hours) get 168:00 using SSRS expression?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

usually the best way is to add your time as seconds to a date and then get the time.

```
=FORMAT(DATEADD("s", Fields!HOURS.Value * 3600, CDATE("1900-01-01")), "hh:mm")
```

Unfortunately, this only works with less than 24 hours. For your 168 hour possibility, you'd need to calculate each time field. Luckily you just need to calculate the minutes.

```
=INT(Fields!HOURS.Value) & ":" & RIGHT("00" & INT(Fields!HOURS.Value * 60 MOD 60), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression

`= Cstr(Cint(Fields!hours.Value)) & ":" & Format(Cint((Fields!hours.Value Mod 1)*60),"00")`

The first part of the expression will take the integer part and convert it to string.

The second part of the expression will take the decimal part, multiply it by 60 (minutes) and format it as two digits.

[image]